# Adding @Input properties to the default Stackblitz standalone component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Trying to do the following in the [default Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhpfkv?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html) Angular application.

```
  @Input()
  set matTypography(matTypography: any) {
    this._hasMatTypography = coerceBooleanProperty(matTypography);
    console.log('fired');
  }

  @HostBinding('class.mat-typography')
  _hasMatTypography: boolean = false;
```

And it's tested like this in `index.html`:

```
  <body>
    <my-app matTypography>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
```

And the `setter` for the `@Input` does not fire.  I think perhaps it's because the `@Input` is on the booted element...

Thoughts?

Comment: It's because you aren't setting the accessor but rather the backing field

Comment: @AluanHaddad IIUC the `@Input` semantics allow for this ...

Comment: Write a Constructor and assign an initial value to the property via the setter. You will see it gets logged.

Comment: That I'm sure of, although I want the property declaration to coerce the value of the backing property.  This article has a demo of the same thing.  If you look at the power button you'll see the `on` input property uses the same approach.  https://fireflysemantics.medium.com/converting-angular-inputs-to-boolean-values-10fd4bdbaba2

Comment: I'll look at it if I get a chance but I can guarantee you it has nothing to do with the coercion.

Comment: You are right.  The coercion part is just to get a boolean assignment on the backing property in order to use it with `@HostBinding`.  I go into this in more detail in the linked article.